# Add dynamic Rows in vf page is clearing previous rows values

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am having this below code in which i am trying to add dynamic rows. But when i click `add Contact Email` button it is clearing the previous rows.

Below Method is called from `add Contact Email` button.

```
addContactEmail()
```

[image]

Below is the apex class -

```
public class accountcontactwrapperclass {

    public Account acc {get;set;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> contactWrapperlist {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> cList;
    public String wrapperId {get; set;}

    public accountcontactwrapperclass (ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        contactWrapperlist = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        acc = new Account();
        cList = new List<Contact>();
        addContact();
    }

    public void addContact(){

        ContactWrapper contWrap = new ContactWrapper();
        ContactEmail contactEmailwrap = new ContactEmail();
        contWrap.contactEmails.add(contactEmailwrap);
        contactWrapperlist.add(contWrap);

    }

    public void addContactEmail(){
        for(ContactWrapper s : contactWrapperlist){
            if(s.wrapperId == wrapperId){
                 s.contactEmails.add(new ContactEmail());
            }   
        } 
    }
// This method is called
    public class ContactEmail{        
        public Contact c1 {get;set;}
    }

    public class ContactWrapper{
        public Contact c {get;set;}
        public string wrapperId {get;set;}
        public List<ContactEmail> contactEmails {get;set;}
        public ContactWrapper(){
            Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
            String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
            wrapperId = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
            contactEmails = new List<ContactEmail>();
            c = new Contact();
        }
    }
```

Below is the vf page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="accountcontactwrapperclass">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <apex:form >

    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Account</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <apex:outputPanel id="accountname">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h5>
                                <div class="field_label " id="closedate">Account Name</div>
                            </h5>
                            <div>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" label="CloseDate" styleClass="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id="subs">
                            <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Contact</div>
                            <div class="panel-body" >
                                <apex:repeat value="{!contactWrapperlist}" var="wrappers">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Last Name</apex:outputLabel>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers.c.LastName}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="subs">
                                        <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Contact Email</div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" >
                                            <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers.contactEmails}" var="wrappers1">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Email</apex:outputLabel>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers1.c1.Email}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Phone</apex:outputLabel>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers1.c1.Phone}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            </apex:repeat>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top: 1.5em;">
                                            <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact Email" action="{!addContactEmail}" reRender="panelId">
                                                <apex:param name="wrapperId" value="{!wrappers.wrapperId}" assignTo="{!wrapperId}" />
                                            </apex:commandbutton>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContact}" reRender="panelId"></apex:commandbutton>

                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi all.. can anyone tell where the issue is happening...

Comment: Please do not add useless comments or make spurious edits to draw attention to your post. If you would like to increase visibility, the appropriate course of action is to offer a bounty.

Comment: sure..Adrian...I was stuggling hoping someone can help me in this issue..

Comment: Yeah that much is clear. You have been on this site long enough you should understand the guidelines though and operate within them.

Comment: Why such complex wrapper structure? And have you debugged your code to see if `contactWrapperlist` has right values after `addContactEmail` method?

Comment: i m seeing this in contactWrapperlist ..(ContactWrapper:[c=Contact:{LastName=cont1}, contactEmails=(ContactEmail:[Email=null, Phone=null, c1=null]), lastname=null, wrapperId=77043216-e7e9-4ed8-3c85-474413069081])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a constructor for `ContactEmail` class and create a new instance of Contact in it. That's it!

```
public class ContactEmail{
        public Contact c1 {get;set;}        
        public ContactEmail()
        {
            c1 = new Contact();
        }
    }
```

Results:

It will retain the values

[image: Contact wrapper]

Comment: So Santanu... Is it not possible using Contact object itself ?.. Because tomorrow if i need to add 100 fields then i need to create 100 variables...Is it possible to change the structure of the wrapper class...

Comment: Hi Santanu.. u saved my day... Can u let me know wht was the issue..

Comment: since, contact instance was not getting created, thats why erasing the values